# Black around PNG in IE Explorer using jquery fade hover

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, png, fadein, transparent

I've searched all day and tried everything to remove the black around my PNGs when I use the Fadein jquery effect in internet explorer.  I must be missing something because all the code I use doesn't fix it.  My page can be visited here: http://www.kaimeramedia.com/derek/Website

I found this bit of code:

```
.item img {
    background: transparent;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#00FFFFFF,endColorstr=#00FFFFFF)";
/* IE8 */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#00FFFFFF,endColorstr=#00FFFFFF);
/* IE6 & 7 */
    zoom: 1;
}
```

but I am unable to get it to work with my menu page ( http://www.kaimeramedia.com/derek/Website/menu.php) which only looks correct in the index.php template.

The images fade on and off fine in all browsers it just that IE 6+ puts a really thick black border around it.  I know there are many sites that discuss this issue, but I haven't had any luck or at least I must be inputting the code wrong.

I tried editing CSS and the style tags below but it didn't seem to have any effect:

```
div.fadehover {
     position: relative;
}

img.b {
     position: absolute;
     left: 0;
     top: 0;

     z-index: 10;
     opacity: 0;
     filter: alpha(opacity=0);
     background: transparent;
}

.style2 {   font-style: italic;     color: #2D6773; }
.style3 {   color: #122833 }
```

If someone could help me with a working solution to my site that would be really appreciated.

Comment: In the end I had to make jpgs that overlayed perfectly with the bg and I made a seperate menu file and index PHP file for IE only that refreshes when it detects the Internet Explorer Browser that is less than or equal to IE8: <!--[if lte IE 8]><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=youralternatesite.com"><![endif]-->;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many solutions to this problem:
1) Use a PNG8 instead
2) Use a js script such as [Unit PNG Fix](http://labs.unitinteractive.com/unitpngfix.php)
3) Try adding `filter: 0` to your image
4) Use and ie filtered background emulating rgba(255,255,255,0)

```
background: transparent;
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#00FFFFFF,endColorstr=#00FFFFFF)"; /* IE8 */   
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#00FFFFFF,endColorstr=#00FFFFFF);   /* IE6 & 7 */      
zoom: 1;
```

5) Finally, if no transparency is needed, just use a jpg

**EDIT:** This is how one of the images looks in png8, I don't see any major differences...
[image: About PNG8]

Comment: These are the same solutions I found on the internet... let's take a look at what you offer:  1.  png8 is not much better than using a gif... I need it to have degrees of transparency.  2. Unit PNG Fix didn't seem to work, but if you can tell me how to make it work with MY site I would welcome it. 3. Filter: 0 did not change it, only worse the image is overlayed until hovered and the black is still visible. 4. If you or someone else can explain emulating rgba in my code that would be useful as I have read about it and tried it with no success.

Comment: 5. The whole point is to figure out how to make the transparency work not step back... if I used a jpeg and wished to change background I would have to change each menu item as well for example.  I'm sure there are many solutions out there, but if someone is willing to show me a working example with my code I would be more than grateful.

Comment: PNG8 is way better than gif if you do it correctly. See edit again.

Comment: I tried Unit PNG fix again and nothing happened... I also tried this bit of code to no avail:

Comment: Yes I have seen this code as I had originally posted it, but I tried putting it in my div.fadehover style and it did not work.  Am I inputing the style in the wrong location or file?  Should it matter if it is in index.php or menu.php?  I appreciate you taking the time to look at it.

Comment: You should put it in your img tag as background. But again, I think png8 might fix your problem and won't affect quality of image.

Comment: that should read that I tried the supersleight jquery and blackness still surrounds...

Comment: I saved off a PNG8 but it doesn't do shadows very well... your above example only looks good on a white background.  However it was worth a shot.

Comment: Works fine for me IE7+ [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/h3zpA/3/). Drop IE6 and problem solved!

Comment: Does it work with the fade in function though?  All my PNGs look okay 100%, but it's the fade function that is causing the issue.  Did you try making it fade over another image?  That is the real problem

Comment: Oh I see, well, no it doesn't. Darn! You'll need a js fix for this I suppose but it's hard for me to test since I'm using ieTester and is buggy as hell with jsFiddle giving me erros all the time.

Comment: Easy solution is to just not do the `fadeIn/fadeOut` in IE9< and solved. It's not worth it!

Comment: Still no success... I'm going to try scripts again

Comment: In the end I have no choice but to fade a jpg matched to the background with a code for IE only.

Comment: After making the jpgs I made a seperate menu file and index PHP file for IE only that refreshes when it detects the Internet Explorer Browser that is less than or equal to IE8: <!--[if lte IE 8]><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://www.youralternatesite.com"><![endif]-->

Answer (score 0):

I've had this exact same problem which is caused by the css filter-property IE requires. In my animation I remove this attribute.

$('elem').css('filter', '');

The old IEs simply cannot perform. You can "outhack" many of IEs flaws with javascript only causing these browsers to slow down even more.

The best solution is graceful degradation and and progressive enhancement (more of that on http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/graceful-degradation-progressive-enhancement/). Don't make IE do things it can't or cannot do well. I know clients have a hard time understanding this but my days of trying to be a magician are over.